# Simple question about the list counting

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list like this `{{a,10},{b,5},{a,5},{b,1}}`.
How to get the result `{a,15},{b,6}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `GroupBy`

```
List @@@ Normal[GroupBy[{{a, 10}, {b, 5}, {a, 5}, {b, 1}}, First -> Last, Total]]
```

> ```
> {{a, 15}, {b, 6}}
> ```

Without associations:

```
Transpose[{#[[All, 1, 1]], Total[#[[All, All, 2]], {2}]}] &[
  GatherBy[{{a, 10}, {b, 5}, {a, 5}, {b, 1}}, First]]
```

Comment: thank you! it works. Do you have another solution which doesn't use "association"?

Comment: @ERT Yes but i think the association one is faster for large lists

Comment: Wonderful! Yes, Association is faster. However, I didn't master the concept of Association yet. Thank you very much. You save me a lot of time. I'm an old-school list-manipulation Mathematica.

Comment: @ERT As a first approximation you can think of an `Association` as a list which uses (almost) arbritrary expressions for indexing.

Answer (score 1):

Just another way:

```
lst = {{a, 10}, {b, 5}, {a, 5}, {b, 1}};
Reap[Sow[#2, #1] & @@@ lst, _, {#1, Total@#2} &][[-1]]
```

yields:

```
{{a, 15}, {b, 6}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = {{a, 10}, {b, 5}, {a, 5}, {b, 1}} ;

Merge[Total][Rule @@@ lst] // KeyValueMap[List]
```

> {{a, 15}, {b, 6}}